# How to attach insulation to Hot End

Tags: extruder

I bought some heating block cotton to insulate the exposed surface of my hot end.  I thought the yellow as double-sticky but it appears to be Kapton.

What can I use to attach it to the extruder?

[image]

My extruder is already covered on four sides.  I want to cover the other two.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Kapton tape would be the logical material. It's unfortunate that your vendor did not supply that as a separate item, rather than sticking it to the "cotton" (I'm guessing not actually cotton, as things might get a bit scorching for cotton, so I'm assuming some type of ceramic fiber or the like.)

Comment: "heating block cotton" is just the common name, the insulation is made of ceramic fiber.  I suspect the pieces are intended to replace the existing material.  I was wanting to try to use it to insulate the other two sides.

Comment: So, cut/punch a hole in a chunk for the filament input tube, stick it over the top, wrap it the "other" way (you may also have to make cutouts for various wires not illustrated...) and kapton-tape the flaps to the bottom after wrapping the ends. That will get you a double-layer on top. Or cut small chunks just to cover the ends and kapton-tape them to the top, bottom and sides, but if you have adequate material to go over the top twice, why not?

Comment: I am considering that; but, that might require disassembling the extruder which I am not sure is worth the effort.

Comment: So, make a slit from an edge to the hole (and to any other holes needed for wires) so you can get it on without disassembling. If need be you can tape those up.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer to the question but closely related, so I venture. I use ordinary wool thread to insulate the hot end. I just wrap it carefully so it is covered everywhere. Very low cost, very effective. Wool can handle even the hottest extrusion temperatures easily.